# Sorting a list based off of values in another list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, listview

I have two lists; `invoice_ordering_list` and `pdfs`. I need to sort `pdfs` based on the order of `invoice_ordering_list`.

```
invoice_ordering_list = ['265189', '265195', '265114', '265166', '265165', '265115']

pdfs = [
    'Est. 57349 April Bill Inv 265115.pdf',
    'AH_202015_JUN_57768 265189.pdf',
    'AH_202015_MAY FEE_265195.pdf',
    'Est. 56534 April Bill Inv 265165.pdf',
    'Est. 57279 April Bill Inv 265166.pdf',
    'Est. 42477 April Bill Inv 265114.pdf',
]
```

I've tried:

```
keydict = dict(zip(pdfs, invoice_ordering_list))
pdfs.sort(key=keydict.get)
```

For some reason it almost gets the order right but `265189` ends up at the end. I must be misunderstanding what's going on here. this seems like such an easy task that I just can't figure out.

The output should be:

```
pdfs_new = [
    'AH_202015_JUN_57768 265189.pdf',
    'AH_202015_MAY FEE_265195.pdf',
    'Est. 42477 April Bill Inv 265114.pdf',
    'Est. 57279 April Bill Inv 265166.pdf',
    'Est. 56534 April Bill Inv 265165.pdf',
    'Est. 57349 April Bill Inv 265115.pdf',
]
```

Comment: `keydict` maps `'Est. 57349 April Bill Inv 265115.pdf'` to `'265189'` (for example). What's the logic behind that?

Comment: your desired output is not in numeric order according to the invoice ordering list.. how are you wanting to sort the list?

Comment: the non numeric list has the invoice numbers in them. So I figured there was a way to sort the `pdfs` list that contains the invoice numbers from the invoice ordering list

Comment: Right now you are pairing the pdfs with and invoice_ordering_list string in order of the array (1st item paired with 1st item, 2nd with 2nd, etc) and then sorting based on the invoice_ordering_list strings, so it basically lines up the pairs in this order: `['265114', '265115', '265165', '265166', '265189', '265195']`. What you instead need to do is extract the invoice number from the PDF string and check where that number exists in the invoice_ordering_list list. Will the pdf strings always have the number right before the ".pdf"?

Comment: @TotZam, ahh ok that makes sense. Yea the the invoice number is always before the ".pdf"

Comment: In that case, you can loop through the pdfs extract the key with `key = re.search('\d+?(?=\.pdf)', pdf).group()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

Step 1: create a dictionary be getting key from the pdf's file name

In this,step I extract the digits only on the last string joined with `.pdf`

```
d={}
for p in pdfs:
 key = re.findall(r'\d+',p.split()[-1].rstrip('.pdf'))[0] 
 d[key] =  p
```

Step 2: creat a new list to store the file name according to the your `invoice_ordering_list`

```
new_pdf=[]
for k in invoice_ordering_list:
  new_pdf.append(d[k])
```

Comment: yea that is the tricky part. The files are very inconsistent with the naming. This solution works great if there is a space before the invoice number. Didn't think to use regular expressions here

Comment: @TimothyMcwilliams yes, I am looking for a regex pattern to get the key,I will update the answer then.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a problem for regex. As discussed in the comments, the actual problem is extracting the number for the sorting key from the pdf file name. I have created a simple match pattern to extract an integer from the end of a pdf file name, and use that as the key for `sort`.

```
import re

pdfs = [
    'Est. 57349 April Bill Inv 265115.pdf',
    'AH_202015_JUN_57768 265189.pdf',
    'AH_202015_MAY FEE_265195.pdf',
    'Est. 56534 April Bill Inv 265165.pdf',
    'Est. 57279 April Bill Inv 265166.pdf',
    'Est. 42477 April Bill Inv 265114.pdf',
]

def pdf_key(s):
    return int(re.search(r'(\d+)\.pdf$',s).group(1))

pdfs.sort(key=pdf_key)

print(pdfs)
```

PS. I use https://regex101.com/ for testing regex match patterns, and it's very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful tip with testing regex! I'll def use this in the future

Answer (score 0):

- Create a dictionary from ordering list with file names as keys and index as values.
- Use `re.search()` to get the id from the file names to match the file names with the indexes from the order dictionary.
- Sort using the index from the order dictionary as the key and zip off the first index to give a sorted list of just the pdf names.

```
order_dict = {val: key for key, val in enumerate(invoice_ordering_list)}

sorted_list = sorted([[el, order_dict[re.search("\d+(?=\.\w+$)", el).group()]] \
                for el in pdfs], key = lambda l: l[1])

sorted_pdfs = [a for a in list(zip(*sorted_list))[0]]
```

**Live Code** -> https://onlinegdb.com/SkoNfFajL

**Or use a function to return the sort key**

```
order_dict = {val: key for key, val in enumerate(invoice_ordering_list)}

def get_key(file):
    id_num = re.search("\d+(?=\.\w+$)", file).group()
    return order_dict[id_num] if id_num in order_dict else int(id_num)

pdfs.sort(key= lambda name: get_key(name))
```

Here, I have the `get_key()` function returning the file id number if it isn't found in the ordering list.

**Live Code** -> https://onlinegdb.com/Sy1zH9ao8